# Free shipping to specific customers group in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods

I need to setup a free shipping method to a certain user group. I can use a custom module (developed for ASM) or create another one, The important thing is how to make "show this Method to this customer group".

Sounds simple, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can you standard Cart Price Rule? Set 100% sales for shipping without any condition (or add condition price rule > 0).

Customer group you can set also in the created rule.